# How to get application package name or UID which is trying to bind my service from onBind function?

Tags: android

I have a service in an application, and I can reach this service from different applications.
And when applications are tried to bind this service I want to know which application is trying to bind my service in onBind function, 
but I can't get the package name or UID of this application in onBind function.

Is it possible to get the application name or UID which is trying to bind my service in onBind function?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the following to determine the calling application.

```
 String callingApp = context.getPackageManager().getNameForUid(Binder.getCallingUid());
```

It's important to note the [JavaDoc for `getCallingUid()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Binder.html#getCallingUid()) which says:

> Return the Linux uid assigned to the process that sent you the current transaction that is being processed. This uid can be used with higher-level system services to determine its identity and check permissions. If the current thread is not currently executing an incoming transaction, then its own uid is returned.

Comment: If I call your supplied code in onBind function, it returns the name of the packageName of apk which service staying in. I mean it not return of caller packageName of another apk, it returns only same packageName which service stays in.

Comment: From the Android documentation,

public static final int getCallingUid ()

Return the ID of the user assigned to the process that sent you the current transaction that is being processed. This uid can be used with higher-level system services to determine its identity and check permissions. If the current thread is not currently executing an incoming transaction, then its own uid is returned.

Comment: Both comments on this answer are correct - but if you call this inside the methods exposed by your AIDL file, it appears to report correctly. A very useful answer for me.

Comment: You need to call `getCAllingUid()` in your binder's method to get the remote app's Uid

Answer (score 6):

The above accepted answer did not worked for me. But a small modification did the trick. This works quite well with [Messenger](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger) based communication.

```
public class BoundService extends Service {

    public static final int TEST = 100;
    private final Messenger messenger = new Messenger(new MessageHandler());

    class MessageHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            String callerId = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getNameForUid(msg.sendingUid);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Calling App: " + callerId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            switch (msg.what) {
                case TEST:
                    Log.e("BoundService", "Test message successfully received.")
                    break;
                default:
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return messenger.getBinder();
    }
}
```

From the above answer, you only need to change from `Binder.getCallingUid()` to `msg.sendingUid`

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this.

onBind() is called from the Android "lifecycle manager" (making up a helpful name), and will only be called once for each Intent (so it can learn which Binder should be returned for that Intent).

The calls to your service then come in over that Binder, and you can do Binder.getCallingUid() in any one of those methods.

Answer (score 5):

**The accepted answer was not quite right!** Why? If two or more applications use the same `android:sharedUserId`, the method `Binder.getCallingUid()` will return a same **uid** and `getPackageManager().getNameForUid(uid)` will return a same string, it looks like: **com.codezjx.demo:10058**, but is not a package name!

The right way is use the **pid**:

```
int pid = Binder.getCallingPid();
```

And then use pid to get package name by `ActivityManager`, each process can hold multiple packages, so it looks like:

```
private String[] getPackageNames(Context context, int pid) {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> infos = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
    if (infos != null && infos.size() > 0) {
        for(RunningAppProcessInfo info : infos) {
            if(info.pid == pid) {
                return info.pkgList;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Warnning**: When using method `Binder.getCallingPid()` and if the current thread is not currently executing an incoming transaction, then its own pid is returned. That means you need to call this method in AIDL exposed interface method.

Comment: This won't work on recent Android versions. getRunningAppProcesses() has been changed to return the calling process only. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619349/android-5-1-1-and-above-getrunningappprocesses-returns-my-application-packag

Comment: The above solution will still work for system apps.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking how `LocationManagerService` restricts access, and here is what I found:

1. They make you pass the package name whenever you try to access location

```java
// android.location.ILocationService

Location getLastLocation(LocationRequest request, String packageName) throws RemoteException;
```

2. When handling the transaction they check if the caller uid matches the package name that was provided (as mentioned in other answers there may be multiple package names that share same uid).

```java
// com.android.server.LocationManagerService

public Location getLastLocation(LocationRequest r, String packageName) {
    ...
    checkPackageName(packageName);

    // From this point on we assume that the provided packageName is the real one
    if (mBlacklist.isBlacklisted(packageName)) {
        if (D) {
            Log.d(TAG, "not returning last loc for blacklisted app: "
                    + packageName);
        }
        return null;
    }
    ...
}
...
private void checkPackageName(String packageName) {
    if (packageName == null) {
        throw new SecurityException("invalid package name: " + null);
    }
    int uid = Binder.getCallingUid();
    String[] packages = mPackageManager.getPackagesForUid(uid);
    if (packages == null) {
        throw new SecurityException("invalid UID " + uid);
    }
    for (String pkg : packages) {
        if (packageName.equals(pkg)) return;
    }
    throw new SecurityException("invalid package name: " + packageName);
}
```

I guess, this is satisfactory, because for the apps to share uid they need to be signed with the same key, so could be equally trusted

Answer (score 1):

You can now use `getPackagesForUid` rather than `getNameForUid`.

(`getName` postPends the uid, `getPackages` does not)

```
class MyService : Service() {


    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder {
        return Messenger(IncomingHandler(this, packageManager).binder
    }

    internal class IncomingHandler(
        private val context: Context,
        private val packageManager: PackageManager
    ) : Handler() {

         override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
            val sendingUid = msg.sendingUid
            val potentialCallingPackageNames = packageManager.getPackagesForUid(sendingUid)!!.toList()
            Log.d("TUT", "One of these packages called you $potentialCallingPackageNames")
         }
    }
}
```

Remember, if you are expecting a system app to call you, then its UID will match a lot of other system apps, so the List will have a lot of items. If it's just another app calling you then likely the List'll have 1 item.