# Security of services or receiver with exported true and without intent filters in Android

Tags: android, security, android-intent, android-activity

Concerning Android security:

1. Can a service or receiver with exported=true and without intent filter create an open door for other applications to send explicit intents which are not manageable by the receiver?
2. Is there an Android feature beyond permissions to protect against this situation?
3. How can a receiver protect itself when use of this mechanism is really necessary?

Comment: What does "not manageable by the receiver" mean? What does "this situation" means? What is "this mechanism"?

Comment: Not manageable by the receiver means: receiving actions that are not expected and can cause side effects.
This situation means: a situation when a receiver receives, from another application, an explicit intent with an action which is not expected.
This mechanism means: the Android inter-application communications (intents) using explicit intents instead of intent filter / implicit intents.
This question is about how to protect Android applications against exploitation when it is necessary to use exported true to receive explicit intents.

Comment: You can disallow caller applications by package. So you can present the user a list of trusted invokers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918731/how-to-get-application-package-name-or-uid-which-is-trying-to-bind-my-service-fr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find some of the answers from the below link

https://www.owasp.org/images/c/ca/ASDC12-An_InDepth_Introduction_to_the_Android_Permissions_Modeland_How_to_Secure_MultiComponent_Applications.pdf