# How to get name of installed or removed application?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have written a broadcast receiver to detect installing and removing applications.
But I want to get the name of installed or removed application too.
How can I do that?

This is my BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class PackageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        switch(intent.getAction())
        {
            case Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED:
                String replaced = "";
                if(intent.getBooleanExtra(Intent.EXTRA_REPLACING, false))
                {
                    replaced = "replaced";
                }
                Log.e("application", "installed " + replaced);

                break;

            case Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED:
                if(!intent.getBooleanExtra(Intent.EXTRA_REPLACING, false))
                {
                    Log.e("application", "removed");
                }

                break;
        }

    }
}
```

In the manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".receivers.PackageReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
         <data android:scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Follow this tutorial:-
 http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/how-to-get-list-of-installed-apps-in-android/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692571/how-can-an-app-detect-that-its-going-to-be-uninstalled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining info found in [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918731/how-to-get-application-package-name-or-uid-which-is-trying-to-bind-my-service-fr) on stack overflow I came up with the following. Intents you are using might have EXTRA_UID extra which contains uid of modified app. With uid you can get the app name. However you can only do that on ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED intent, because in ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED app was already remove and you cant get its name (you can still get uid).

Check this sample:

```
int uid = intent.getIntegerExtra(Intent.EXTRA_UID);
String appName = context.getPackageManager().getNameForUid(uid);
```

So in your case it would be:

```
public class PackageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        switch(intent.getAction())
        {
            case Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED:
                String replaced = "";
                String appName = "";
                int uid = -1;
                if(intent.getBooleanExtra(Intent.EXTRA_REPLACING, false))
                {
                    replaced = "replaced";
                }
                uid = intent.getIntExtra(Intent.EXTRA_UID, -1);
                if(uid != -1){
                    appName = context.getPackageManager().getNameForUid(uid);
                }
                Log.e("application", "installed " + replaced + " uid " + uid + " appname " + appName);

                break;

            case Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED:
                if(!intent.getBooleanExtra(Intent.EXTRA_REPLACING, false))
                {
                    Log.e("application", "removed");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

With this code I've seen this written in logcat after installing Google Earth from Google Play:

> installed  uid 10404 appname com.google.earth

Comment: The input of getNameForUid method is an int not String.

Comment: However I tried this: int installedUid = intent.getIntExtra(Intent.EXTRA_UID, -1);
                String installedAppName = context.getPackageManager().getNameForUid(installedUid); and it returns null

Comment: @MR.Iraji See if String returned by intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_UID) is a number, if so try parsing it to a int with `Integer.parseInt(uid)`.

Comment: It is write in developer.android.com: EXTRA_UID containing the integer uid previously assigned to the package. However as I said before, I have tried it and getNameForUid(uid) method returned null to me.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will now try do research this problem further. Wait for my answer.

Comment: @MR.Iraji I've updated my answer. This method doesn't work on app removal, but I don't think there is method that works. With this you get package name. Tell me if you want name from launcher and I will add it to my answer

Comment: I now understand that if I install an application this code returns package name of installed application. But if I remove an application this code returns null to me because after removing an application, the package name of application doesn't exist anymore. So getNameForUid(uid) method returns null to me.

Comment: Yes, package doesnt exists so you can't get it's name.

Comment: So I need to get name of application just before it removes. do you know how to do it?

Comment: If you know the answer please tell me. however you brought me closer to the answer. thank you very much.

Comment: You can get all apps(with names and uids) on first application run, and keep track which application was added/removed based on uid.