# How to restrict bound service to be called by particular packages

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

I have written a bound service and I would like this service to be only called from particular app. I do not want other apps to be able to make calls to this service.

The options I know so far are:

1. Use a permission. There seems to be 3 secured permission, dangerous, signature and signatureOrSystem. Unfortunately, none of these permissions will work for me as I don't want users to accept this permission also both app does not have same signature and these are not system app.
2. Get app name on service bind or when making a call to service. I looked up a way to do this on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12918906/5446940). This unfortunately does not works for me as it always returns the app ID in which the service resides.

Is there any other option for me or I can use the above mentioned options with some change to achieve the desired requirement.

Bound Service Code

```
public class SampleCommsService extends Service {

    private static Messenger messanger;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.e("TEST", "package intent: " + intent.getPackage());
        String callingApp = MyApplication.getAppContext().getPackageManager().getNameForUid(Binder.getCallingUid());
        Log.e("TEST", "onBind - package name: " + callingApp);
        return getMyBinder();
    }

    private synchronized IBinder getMyBinder() {
        if (messanger == null) {
            messanger = new Messenger(new SettingsProcessor());
        }
        return messanger.getBinder();
    }

    class SettingsProcessor extends Handler {

        private static final int GET_SETTINGS_REQUEST = 1;
        private static final int UPDATE_SETTINGS_RESPONSE = 2;
        private static final String SETTINGS = "settings";

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            String callingApp = MyApplication.getAppContext().getPackageManager().getNameForUid(Binder.getCallingUid());
            Log.e("TEST", "handle message - package name: " + callingApp);

            switch (msg.what) {
                case GET_SETTINGS_REQUEST:
                    sendSettingsValue(msg);
                    break;
                default:
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }

        private void sendSettingsValue(Message msg) {
            try {
                Message resp = Message.obtain(null, UPDATE_SETTINGS_RESPONSE);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putBoolean(SETTINGS, MyApplication.isSettingsEnabled());
                resp.setData(bundle);
                msg.replyTo.send(resp);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // ignore
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output on calling api:

```
02-01 15:21:03.138 7704-7704/my.service.package E/TEST: package intent: null
02-01 15:21:03.139 7704-7704/my.service.package E/TEST: onBind - package name: my.service.package
02-01 15:21:12.429 7704-7704/my.service.package E/TEST: handle message - package name: my.service.package
```

Comment: AFAIK, the techniques shown in that question work. You might want to provide a [mcve] demonstrating what you tried.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'll add a code sample. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I was able to solve this problem based on a given answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12918906/5446940). The answer given in the link obviously does not works, but you can get the app ID from the Handler used for the bound service.

```
class SettingsProcessor extends Handler {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            String callingApp = MyApplication.getAppContext().getPackageManager().getNameForUid(msg.sendingUid);
            Log.e("TEST", "handle message - package name: " + callingApp);
        }
    }
```

Instead of `Binder.getCallingUid()`, I am using `msg.sendingUid` and it works fine for me.