# Is it possible for two Android processes to have the same name?

Tags: android

I'm thinking of ways to secure an AIDL call in Android without using any support libraries, just the Android SDK. One way I thought of was to enforce that the binder being used has a whitelisted process name, e.g. com.xyz.app. This is possible with [How to get application package name or UID which is trying to bind my service from onBind function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918731/how-to-get-application-package-name-or-uid-which-is-trying-to-bind-my-service-fr)

However, is it still possible for a malicious app to just specify in their manifest that their process name is the same as a whitelisted process name?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,two applications can use the same process name.
Two advices for you:
1.After checking the process name,you still need to check the signature of the app.
Other apps can use the same name with you , but they can't use the same signature.

```
 //the code showing how to get siginature
 PackageInfo info = getPackageInfoByName(context, pkgName);
 byte[] sign = info.signatures[0].toByteArray();

 //Add code here check whether the sign with your app


 public static PackageInfo getPackageInfoByName(Context context, String packageName) {
    try {
        return context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName,PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed getPackageInfo", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

2.You can add an signature level permission for your service which work as the server of binder.

```
//1.create a signature level permission in your AndroidManifest.xml
<permission
        android:name="com.xyz.aa.permission.bindservice"
        android:protectionLevel="signature">
</permission>

//2.Add the permission to your service 
 <service android:name=".MyService" 
        android:permission="com.xyz.aa.permission.bindservice">
    </service>
```

The app who want to bind the service should use this permission,only apps using same signature with you can use this permission.